# Rate limiting observables

Tags: rx-java

I have an observable that produces data from a fast stream from a database cursor. I'm looking to throttle the output on a rate of x items per second. So far I've been using Callstack blocking as described on the docs:

```
observable.map(f -> {
ratelimiter.acquire(); // configured limiter to only allow
});
```

This is working fine, but just out of curiosity is there a better way to handle this using backpressure?

Tks

Comment: Do you want ` delay` or `throttleFirst(throttleLast)`? The latter will drop the items if receiving items too fast.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sample` (throttleLast) operator:

```
Observable<T> throttled = 
    observable.sample(1 / rate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure

Comment: `sample` will drop data, which I don't think Vinicius want.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `rx.Observable#onBackpressureBuffer()` combined with a custom subscriber that will periodically request `n` items per second. But, you would be bound to *hard* one second sampling.

*Note* `.subscribeOn()` and `.toBlocking()` is only to make the main method not exit immediately.

```java
public class BackpressureTest {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Observable.range(1, 1000)
      .compose(Observable::onBackpressureBuffer) // consume source immediately, but buffer it
      .lift(allowPerSecond(3)) // via operator using custom subscriber request n items per second
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .toBlocking()
      .subscribe(System.out::println);
  }

  private static <T> Observable.Operator<T, T> allowPerSecond(final int n) {
    return upstream -> periodicallyRequestingSubscriber(upstream, n);
  }

  private static <T> Subscriber<T> periodicallyRequestingSubscriber(final Subscriber<T> upstream, final int n) {
    return new Subscriber<T>() {

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
        request(0); // request 0 so that source stops emitting
        Observable.interval(1, SECONDS).subscribe(x -> request(n)); // every second request n items
      }

      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
        upstream.onCompleted();
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(final Throwable e) {
        upstream.onError(e);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(final T integer) {
        upstream.onNext(integer);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the `.compose(Flowable::onBackpressureBuffer)` needed for? can't you just directly call `.onBackpressureBuffer()`?

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @michalsamek seems right, although backpressure only works for Flowables. I've corrected his subscriber, so that it does what is requested.

There was also a slight problem when using it in bursts at different times.

```
private static <T> FlowableOperator<T, T> allowPerMillis(int millis) {
    return observer -> new PeriodicallyRequestingSubscriber<>(observer, millis);
}


Observable.range(1, 100)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .compose(Flowable::onBackpressureBuffer)
    .lift(allowPerMillis(200))
    .subscribe(value -> System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() % 10_000 + " : " + value));



public class PeriodicallyRequestingSubscriber<T> implements Subscriber<T> {

    private final Subscriber<T> upstream;

    private final int millis;

    // If there hasn't been a request for a long time, do not flood
    private final AtomicBoolean shouldRequest = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public PeriodicallyRequestingSubscriber(Subscriber<T> upstream, int millis) {
        this.upstream = upstream;
        this.millis = millis;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
        Observable
                .interval(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe(x -> {
                   if (shouldRequest.getAndSet(false))
                       subscription.request(1);
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T t) {
        shouldRequest.set(true);
        upstream.onNext(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        upstream.onError(throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        upstream.onComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the `.compose(Flowable::onBackpressureBuffer)` needed for? can't you just directly call `.onBackpressureBuffer()`?